# Python making screencaputure program with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make my own screencapture program with Python.

What I intended is;

- Run program
- Click 'ON' button
- Press 'Shift Z' (or whatever shortcut key)
- Do 2 clicks with an interval time
- Capture the only screen with calculating 2 x,y coordinates which I got from 2 clicks.

Here is my code so far.

```
import pyautogui as pag
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import win32api

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Mycapture')
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 200)
canvas1.pack()

on = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'on.png')
off = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'off.png')

def myScreenshot(event):

if '<Button-1>':
    start = pag.position()
    
    
if ' <Button-1>':
    end = pag.position()
    
xx = start[0]
yy = start[1]
ww = end[0] - start[0]
hh = end[1] - start[1]

myScreenshot = pag.screenshot(region=(xx,yy,ww,hh))
myScreenshot.save('D:/capture.jpg')

def capture():
    if onButton['image'] == str(off):
        onButton.config(image = on, bd=0)
        root.bind('<Shift-Z>', myScreenshot)
    else:
        onButton.config(image = off, bd=0)
        root.unbind('<Shift-Z>')
    

onButton = tk.Button(image = off, command=capture, bd=0)
canvas1.create_window(200, 50, window=onButton)

root.mainloop()
```

But this occurs error for some reason.
Can anyone advise me what was wrong with my code?

Or please let me know how I can use X,Y coordinates which I got from pyautogui.position() with screencapture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: coudl you provide us with an error you are getting?

Comment: The code, as is, doesn't make much sense. For one, the indentation in what's pasted here is wrong, and those `if`s will always evaluate to true...